# What is correct api key name in headers

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I'm using this module https://www.drupal.org/project/services_api_key_auth, it states that you can either put the **api_key** in query string or inside header. In query it works like this `domain.com/api/pages?api_key=SOMEKEY234729372375`. Passing this key and value in header doesn't work. I've browsed the module's code and found:

```
 $header_api_key = $request->headers->get('apikey');
    if (!empty($header_api_key)) {
      return $header_api_key;
    }
```

So I've tried to name my header **apikey**. Still no response.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that looks for the API key is in [`ApiKeyAuth::getKey()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/services_api_key_auth/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Authentication/Provider/ApiKeyAuth.php#L106).

```php
  public function getKey(Request $request) {
    $form_api_key = $request->get('api_key');
    if (!empty($form_api_key)) {
      return $form_api_key;
    }

    $query_api_key = $request->query->get('api_key');
    if (!empty($form_api_key)) {
      return $query_api_key;
    }

    $header_api_key = $request->headers->get('apikey');
    if (!empty($header_api_key)) {
      return $header_api_key;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
```

Effectively, the values that authentication provider looks for are:

- *api_key* in `$_POST` data
- *api_key* in the query string (which isn't used, due to a bug in the code)
- *apikey* in the headers

Using the correct key name isn't sufficient. The value passed in that key must be associated to a user, or [`ApiKeyAuth::authenticate()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/services_api_key_auth/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Authentication/Provider/ApiKeyAuth.php#L62) will return an empty array. (It should return `NULL` if the authentication fails, but this should not probably cause any issue.)

```php
  public function authenticate(Request $request) {
    // Load config entity.
    $api_key_entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('api_key')
      ->loadMultiple();
    foreach ($api_key_entities as $key_item) {

      if ($this->getKey($request) == $key_item->key) {
        $accounts = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user')->loadByProperties(array('uuid' => $key_item->user_uuid));
        $account = reset($accounts);

        if (isset($account)) {
          return $account;
        }
        break;
      }
    }

    return [];
  }
```

Keep in mind that, in the case there are more authentication providers that apply to the same route, Drupal will use just one, after sorting them according to priority using [`krsort()`](http://php.net/krsort). (See [`AuthenticationCollector::getSortedProviders()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Authentication%21AuthenticationCollector.php/function/AuthenticationCollector%3A%3AgetSortedProviders/8.9.x).)
In this case, it can happen the used authentication provider isn't the expected one, which is then unable to authenticate the user.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. The value of the key is associated to the existing user. The view that is restricted consists of subviews. All of them are restricted only with api_key module's method and role - api_consumer (role of the user that has the api key). There's also basic auth on on the server, but it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: There is 404 and empty array when I set api_key header and use GET. With POST I get 405, method not allowed.

Comment: Any authentication provider may interfere with another one, as long as they both apply to the same route. The *api_key* provider applies to every route, as long as the API key is provided together the route; the chance of interference is high. As for the 404 error, it means the route isn't found. That isn't related to the authentication provided, which eventually causes a 403 error. The 405 error is also caused from the route, which cannot be accessed using POST.

Comment: May I have the last question, please? How to set the view? Authentication: api_key_auth and what Access ? if unrestricted, the endpoint is open, if set to role - it works only with query param, not header.

Comment: I think I've managed to get things work. I've used other module, very similar https://www.drupal.org/project/key_auth, the thing I was missing was that with this module I can set the view to use permissions related to the module. The module gets the user by key and checks the permissions. Also the key is not a configuration entity which was a problem for me, it's connected to the user in db. THANK YOU, without you I could not find it.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 I am trying to create a secure login. For that I want to disable the default login route and use a login link with a secret key per user. I found key auth module and I thought may be this is what I am looking for. I have created a route subscriber to provide alternate user login, but I do not know how to call the key in the login path.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 My purpose is to make it difficult to access login page and have a per user unique login path. When I use /user/login?api-key=somekey, it works, but still the default user/login is also accessible.

Comment: Try to differentiate user role permissions, so that user that has a key, has different permission set. Please make a new post, so we can fully understand the need.